# How to normalize table1 in postgres sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-normalization, first-normal-form

[image]I need to normalize (in a technical way) table1 by splitting the column "error occured at" so that it was like in table2.

Is there is any DML function that will help me solve this? So that the rest of the information was transferred without using lead-lag function?

I tried to used string_to_array and transpose functions.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Clearly this is likely a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH split_dates AS (
  SELECT other_columns..., unnest(string_to_array(error_occured_at, ', '))::date AS date
  FROM table1
  WHERE error_occured_at RLIKE "," -- Only considering rows that actually do contain a comma
)
INSERT INTO table1 (other_columns..., error_occured_at)
SELECT other_columns..., date
FROM split_dates;
```

If you want to then delete rows where `error_occured_at` is of the older format, you can do:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE error_occured_at RLIKE ","
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by combine `unnest` with `string_to_array` as follows :

```
SELECT store_name, subject_of_collection, cost, checkpoint, errors_found, s. error_occured_at
FROM   table1, unnest(string_to_array(error_occured_at, ', ')) as s(error_occured_at)
```